# how to implement the variable array with one and zero in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm totally new on tensorflow, and I just want to implement a kind of selection function by using matrices multiplication.

example below:

```py
#input:
I = [[9.6, 4.1, 3.2]]

#selection:(single "1" value , and the other are "0s")
s = tf.transpose(tf.Variable([[a, b, c]]))
e.g.  s could be [[0, 1, 0]] or [[0, 0, 1]] or [[1, 0, 0]]

#result:(multiplication)
o = tf.matul(I, s)
```

sorry for the poor expression, 
    I intend to find the 'solution'  in distribution functions with different means and sigmas. (value range from 0 to 1). 
so now, i have three variable  i, j, index.

```py
value1 = np.exp(-((index - m1[i]) ** 2.) / s1[i]** 2.)
value2 = np.exp(-((index - m2[j]) ** 2.) / s2[j]** 2.)
m1 = [1, 3, 5]  s = [0.2, 0.4, 0.5]. #first graph
m2 = [3, 5, 7]. s = [0.5, 0.5, 1.0]. #second graph
```

I want to get the max or optimization of total value

e.g. value1 + value2 = 1+1 = 2  and one of the solutions: i = 2, j=1, index=5

or I could do this in the other module?

Comment: Could you give some more details about what your intention is ?

Comment: I just edited the post. sorry for the poor expression. it's really hard.